# Gatsby website displays 404 page for other github pages repos

Tags: javascript, url-routing, github-pages, gatsby, netlify

I am using Github Pages and Netlify to host my site. It is a static site that uses Gatsby. I also am using a custom domain. Everything works fine for the main site. Index and all the other pages display as expected.

However, I have other repos that use github pages, that I set to also use my domain. When the link is clicked to open the project page, it instead goes to my websites 404 page. When I use the default url that github pages gives the website for the project loads fine.

Comment: I imagine you can't have multiple repos on the same domain. This explains it: https://tink.uk/using-a-custom-domain-with-multiple-github-repositories/

Answer (score 0):

There are some ways to solve this, but depend on your use case and the way you want to feed up your links.

### Subdomain Solution

Have your GitHub pages subdomain for the pages

`CNAME`

```
mysub.example.com
```

Make a `CNAME` entry in your DNS for the `mysub` name and give it a value of `YOUR-GITHUB-USERNAME.github.io` replacing `YOUR-GITHUB-USERNAME` with your username on github.

### Redirects Solution

Include a `_redirects` file to the root of your build folder for Netlify to serve up the path(s) you want to `proxy`.

`_redirects`

```
/mysub/*  https://username.github.io/:splat  200!
```

***NOTE***: In Gatsby, you place the redirects in `static/_redirects`. If you are using the `gatsby-plugin-netlify` in your Gatsby project, you could optionally setup the above in that configuration ([see readme](https://github.com/gatsbyjs/gatsby/tree/master/packages/gatsby-plugin-netlify)), but the above is still compatible.